# What is the lenovo "Keyboard Manager" application and what "Unknown Software" could be included with it?

Tags: security, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

Today I ran Lenovo's System Update on my ThinkPad W541 laptop (windows 10) to try to fix a problem unrelated to this question. In the [readme](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1wvu26w.txt) of the latest version (9.0.0.6 Released 2017/09/27) of [*Hotkey Features Integration*](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds120449) there was a *fix* which I found alarming. (In bold below)

> ### Summary of Changes
>
> Where: <   >        Package version number
>            [Important]  Important update
>            (New)        New function or enhancement
>            (Fix)        Correction to existing function
>
> #### Version 9.0.0.6
>
> - (FIX) Fixed CapsLock and NumLock OSD issue that the screen configuration
>         setting function in display adaptor properties control panel may not
>         work.
> - (FIX) **Fixed issue that contents of Keyboard Manager application selector dialog may include some unknown software**.

What does this mean? Is it simply a security vulnerability (like the [notepad++ CIA hack](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.3.3-fix-cia-hacking-issue.html)) where a malicious piece of software could hook itself into the keyboard driver or is it worse and a malicious and unknown software had been packaged in the previous version of the driver? How can someone get more information about a change like this?

Lenovo lists this as an *Optional Update* in its *System Update* app (the lowest of three priority categories). But the language of the fix sounds more serious than optional to me.

Comment: `How can someone get more information about a change like this? ` - I'd say...contact Lenovo, maybe? IMHO, it's the only way to get *reliable* information about this for anyone of us.

Comment: Thanks @flolilolilo  I thought to contact lenovo too, but I figure that I'll have to wade through a lot of customer service tiers before I get (if I get) to someone who knows the details of this release. I was hoping someone here might have past experience with similar lenovo release notes or would otherwise have some helpful nugget of information.  I may in the future try this, and if I get a response, I'll post it as an answer here for the next guy.

Comment: There is an option to bind a custom app to Fn+F12. It allows you to add some applications from your PC to a some kind of a list for further run. My guess would be: there probably was a bug, so non-existent (or no longer present in system) software could be selected from that list.